# Amazon EC2 Free Tier Usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I signed up for Amazon free usage tier where i get a micro instance free for a year. 
If i terminate the free instance and start a new micro instance, will i be charged for the new instance or will it be free?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get 750 free hours of Linux micro instance time per month for one year after signing up for your AWS account.

It's up to you how you use it: you can run one instance for the whole year, or you can run multiple instances for shorter periods. It's completely OK to stop and start instances.

See http://aws.amazon.com/free/ for details.

Comment: just calling out that it is 750 hours per month for 1 year

Answer (score 2):

It will be free until you get to your first year anniversary.  You can actually turn on 750 micro instances for one hour, and it will be free as well. After the first hour you will be charge of course.

Answer (score 0):

Note that EBS storage does cost you over 10GB on the elastic block storage. Ubuntu stock images are 15GB, for example, you can end up with a small bill unless you check each of the criteria carefully.

Comment: Installed stock Ubuntu 10.04 32bit on 8gig of EBS. Everything under control except i'm getting charged for "regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 Avail Zones or when using public/elastic IP addresses or ELB". I have only one instance, use no elastic IP or ELB. Strange!